# Android prevent views overlap on drag and drop

Tags: android

I am adding some ImageViews to a relative layout dynamically (on touch points)
Any ImageView has an OnTouchListener. In Action Move I move the ImageView(sth like Drag and Drop). 
My problem is that ImageViews may overlap each other when they are moving. I want to prevent them from overlap in any way! (best is stop moving when collision happen)

[Look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTvAy.png)

All ImageViews are saved in a link list. I get the x & y of moving view and compare it with other views and if they had collision don't let them moving. 
But I want that user can make them separate again. How can I do this work?
In brief when views collision happen I don't let them move any more but I want if the move was making them far from each other it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Rect rc1 = new Rect();
 imageView1.getDrawingRect(rc1);
 Rect rc2 = new Rect();
 imageView2.getDrawingRect(rc2);
 if (Rect.intersects(rc1, rc2) {
   // intersection is detected
   // here is your method call
 }
```